# regex/split sentence

Tags: javascript, regex, split

I have a sentence which contains attributes : `"hey how <span target="">you</span>"`

I would like to put `'hey', 'how', '<span target="">you</span>'` in an array.

I used `string.split(' ')` and got `['hey','how','<span','target="">you</span>']`

Is it possible to split all the words and use at the same time the regex in order to catch the words which begin with `<` and finish with `>` ?

Thank you

Comment: Parsing HTML with regex is [dangerous territory](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/382456), why do you need this?

Comment: I have a sentence : "hello how are you" (example) and I have to extract each words in an array and sometimes there are some html tags... So what do you suggest if it is not appropriate ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If level of nested HTML tags is zero then this would help:

```js
console.log('hey how <span target="">you</span>'.match(/(?!<)\S+|<(\w+)\b[^]*?\/\1>/g));
```

Answer (score 0):

regex should not be used to parse html - [RegEx match open tags except XHTML self-contained tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags)

maybe you should ues jQuery?

```
$("#txt").text()
```

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick, but as @Scott mentioned regex may not be the appropriate way to handle html depending on your data.

```js
const regex = /\<.+?>.*?\<.+?>|\S+/g;
const str = `hey how <span target="">you</span>`;

console.log(str.match(regex));
```

Comment: Thank you ! So what do you suggest if it is not appropriate ?

Answer (score 0):

I would say don't parse html using Regex. Using jquery or javascript functions is much more easy and safe.

For,

```
<div id="sentence">
  hey how <span target="">you</span>
<div>
```

Do something on the lines of

```
$("#sentence").text() // JQuery
```

or

```
document.getElementById("sentence").innerText // Javascript
```

Both will give you -> hey how you